# Is the following set algebra correct? i am getting the following answer. A' U B. However, the answer apparently is A'

Tags: discrete-mathematics

````
(A U B')' U A' = A'
= A' B U A'         
= A' U (A' U B)
= (A' U A') U B
= A' U B

[P.S: A' stands for "A's complement" or "not A" ]
```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Allowing for some sloppiness in notation, your first equality of sets seems okay but the next line goes off the track.  Parentheses would help.  Mathematical notation here allows for intersection (`\cap`) and union (`\cup`).  See this [brief introduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am assuming you want to solve this by "Set Algebra."

$$
\begin{align}
\overline{(A \cup \overline{B})} \cup \overline{A} = \overline{A}
\end{align}
$$

Above is what we want to prove. So,

$$
\begin{align}
\overline{(A \cup \overline{B})} \cup \overline{A} && \text{Given} \\
= (\overline{A} \cap \overline{\overline{B}}) \cup \overline{A} && \text{DeMorgan's Law} \\
= (\overline{A} \cap B) \cup \overline{A} && \text{Complement Law} \\
=  \overline{A} && \text{Absorption Law}
\end{align}
$$

To prove the absorption law:
$$
x \in (\overline{A} \cap B) \cup \overline{A} \\
x \in \overline{A} \lor x\in (\overline{A} \cap B) \\
x \in \overline{A} \lor (x \in \overline{A} \land x \in B) \\ 
\text{ by Disjunction Absorbs Conjunction} \quad x \in \overline{A} 
$$